# How to make ComboBox Dropdown to draw in Upward direction

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

In Winform, i have a ComboBox at the bottom of the form. 
when i run the application, ComboBox draws dropdown list in downward direction which goes out of the form borders.

how can i make ComboBox Dropdown list to draw in Upward direction ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not immediate but you can do it, I'll just outline the steps you need:

- Attach an event handler to `ComboBox.DropDown`.
- Convert the Left/Bottom location of the `ComboBox` to screen cordinates and add them an offset (+1 for example to both values).
- Use use `WindowFromPoint()` to get the handle of the dropped down window (it's below the control, that's why +1).
- Get the bounds of the dropped window (you can use `CB_GETDROPPEDCONTROLRECT` or `GetWindowRect()`, as you prefer).
- Move the window to the new location (`ComboBox` top - dropped down window height) using `MoveWindow()`.

That's all

**EDIT**
Note that you may merge point 2 and 4, with a single `SendMessage` with `CB_GETDROPPEDCONTROLRECT` you can get the bounds of that window and the location to use as parameter for `WindowFromPoint()`. In this way you do not assert that the dropped down window is always downward (it's not sure when the window touches the screen bounds and it may even change in future versions).

Comment: if you have any sample code, can you please post the link for the same.

Comment: @EthanHunt sorry, no sample code or code examples. Basically you have to DllImport function you'll use (SendMessage, WindowFromPoint and MoveWindow) then follow the list pretty directly.