# How can i make an upward-expanding combobox in C# Windows Forms. Is there any possible way to do this?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am facing a challenge in C# Windows Forms where I need to create a combobox that expands upwards rather than downwards.

While I have attempted to develop this functionality using a custom ComboBox class, my efforts have not been successful.

I am seeking guidance on how to effectively implement this feature.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Please don't break your users' muscle memory. Comboboxes expand down by default, but expand up if there is no space below to expand down.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make ComboBox Dropdown to draw in Upward direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816650/how-to-make-combobox-dropdown-to-draw-in-upward-direction)

Comment: When you need to handle the ListControl of a ComboBox directly, you usually call `GetComboBoxInfo()` to get its handle (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61154093/7444103)). When you have the handle, you can do what you want -- As already mentioned, unless you have a very good reason (e.g., and the automatic feature does not provide the expected result in some contexts, or the ListControl is detached from the ComboBox in some scrolling event scenario - this [can happen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68011637/7444103)), don't introduce unexpected behaviors, your users won't appreciate it